# Proving that a hypothetical logical operator is not truth functional

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A logical operator is said to be truth functional when the truth value of sentences in which it is the major operator is dependent only on the truth values of component atomic sentences. For example, the negation operator is truth functional because the truth value of $\neg A$ is dependent only on the truth value $A$.

How do you show that the hypothetical logical operator $ H(X) \leftrightarrow  $ "It is necessary that $X$" is not truth functional?

In my attempt, I provide 2 distinct true sentences $ A $ and $ B $ such that $H(A)$ is true but $H(B)$ is false. Namely, A = "1 + 1 = 2" and B = "Humans exist." Because the truth or falsity of $H(X)$ is not fixed when $X$ is true, it cannot be said to be dependent on the truth value of $X$ alone.

Is this proof satisfactory? Also, is there a more rigorous proof?

Comment: Your proof is fine, and I am not aware of any more "rigorous" proofs. Your example shows sufficiently that the operator yields different output truth values for the same input truth value, and can hence not be truth-functional.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe the proof can be made more precise by stating that an alternative rendering for the definition of a truth function $H$ is simply $H:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. It's much clearer than saying "$H$ is truth functional if the truth value of $H(X)$ is dependent only on the truth value of $X$". However, it is interesting to see that they mean the same.

Comment: The key point that brings the two formulations together is that H must be a *function* on truth values: For the same input truth value, there must always be the same output truth value. The truth value of $H(X)$ is "dependent only on the truth value of $X$" precisely in the sense that H is a function from the truth value of $X$, and only the truth value of $X$. Since $H([[A]]) = H(1) = 1 \neq 0 = H(1) = H([[B]])$, $H$ can not be a function, which is what your argument shows.

Comment: BTW, one should be a bit careful about distinguishing the operator from its (hypothetical) truth function: Either you write $H(A)$, which means that $H$ is a sentential operator (a syntactic object) that is applied to propositions to yield a new proposition: $PROP^n \to PROP$. Or you write $H(1)$ (which in your case is = $H([[A]])$, where $[[A]]$ is the truth value of $A$), in which case $H$ is a truth function $\{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}$. An operator and its semantics are not exactly the same thing, and should, strictly speaking, be notationally kept apart.

Comment: Note to self: An alternative choice for B exists that doesn't use the existential quantifier (e.g.  "The earth is less than 5 billion years old")

Also, intuitively, if $ A \rightarrow B $ is a tautology, then "It is neccessary that $ B $" follows from "It is necessary that $ A $". And "It is not necessary that $ B $" follows from "It is not necessary that $ A $". Furthermore, in general, "It is not necessary that $ A $" isn't equivalent to "It is necessary that $ \neg A $"